# How can I query a superclass table without picking up the subclass in JPA?

Tags: jpa

Is there a simple way in JPA to query a super class table without it auto-magically joining to the subclass table and constructing complete objects? Consider I have a Person class and a subclass of Person called Male (just for example). They use an Join Strategy for inheritance. Can I query for Person instances without picking up the Male attributes (concrete Person instances without instances of Male)? I'm pretty sure the simple answer is to use aggregation instead of inheritance but before changing things I wanted to see if it is possible with inheritance.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get the person values from the Male entity?

Comment: I would like to query the Person table without joining to Male or Female tables and just get the Person attributes.